Transfer file via ssh with only echo and cat command
Due to some constraints, i have to transfer local file to remote ssh with only echo and cat command and here-document.
I've tried:
#!/bin/bash
SSH_CMD=xxx # suppose `SSH_CMD` is my ssh command
w="$(cat word)"
SSH_CMD <<EOF1
cd /data00
touch for-test
echo $w >> for-test
echo "abc" >> for-test
EOF1

And word is a file with multiple lines:
#!/bin/bash
line1
line2
line3

After i run the script, the /data00/for-test file only contains one line: abc, quite strange.

Why not just SSH_CMD 'cat > /data00/for-test' < word? You can use a 2nd command for "abc" within a heredoc the same way. Or just echo "abc" | SSH_CMD 'cat >> /data00/for-test'.  Or even just SSH_CMD 'echo "abc" >> /data00/for-test' for the second part. (this assumes your SSH_CMD is equivalent to ssh user@host)

Rather than the content of word disappearing from the output file, it seems more likely to me that the file word has DOS line endings and so when you cat it after the ssh all you see is abc because the CRs from word are overwriting the content of word in the display. See why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it for more information on that. Not quoting $w isn't helping any, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

No need for your convoluted loading of source file in a variable.
# suppose SSH_CMD is my ssh command
SSH_CMD 'cat > /data0/for-test; echo "abc" >> /data0/for-test' < word

Here is how it works:

< word: Feeds the word file to ssh
cat > /data0/for-test; echo "abc" >> /data0/for-test: Commands executed at the remote host:

cat > /data0/for-test: Redirects the input stream to the /data0/for-test file locally on the remote server.
echo "abc" >> /data0/for-test: Adds abc to the /data0/for-test file.



As a bonus, it can transfer binary files as well.

It's more reliable to pass the definition of w to remote machine:
SSH_CMD=(ssh ...) # suppose `SSH_CMD` is my ssh command
w="$(cat word)"
{ declare -p w 
  cat <<'EOF1'
cd /data00
touch for-test
echo "$w" >> for-test
echo "abc" >> for-test
EOF1
} | "${SSH_CMD[@]}"


Using echo "$w" >> for-test is unsafe. First it can interpret dash options from the string, it will also alter the original content with a newline. Use printf %s "$w" instead with predictable result and no added newline.

You have to wrap $w with "" than it'll work, like this:
#!/bin/bash
SSH_CMD=xxx # suppose `SSH_CMD` is my ssh command
w=$(cat word)
SSH_CMD <<EOF1
cd /data00
touch for-test
echo "$w" >> for-test
echo "abc" >> for-test
EOF1

Also note that "" around $(cat word) are not needed.
